# How to solve Tumblr image resizing on a static page?

Tags: tumblr, resolution, autoresize, static-pages

I'm working on a Tumblr blog and I want to put big images in a static page called "about".
I found a lot of solutions for the image resizing but i didn't work with my issue, maybe because I'm not using images in *photo posts* but just on a static page.

Anyone knows how can I solve the problem?

This is the link of the page I'm talking about:
http://athanormag.tumblr.com/about

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What you want is not clear. Do you want to have small images that will zoom in on click like this one? http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: no, I just want big and good quality images on a static page of Tumblr. When I set the images with a width of 100% they get bigger but in low quality. I saw a few guides to fix the problem in posts, but it doesn't work, maybe because I'm working on a static page.

Comment: The issue is that the html structure for static pages is very similar to the structure of the main blog. You could insert custom HTML into the about page and then style that separately, I think that is the quickest solution. Something I have done in the past is to detect pages in the url using jquery and set different css according to that, but it's more hacky and requires  a fair bit more code.

Comment: When you upload an image for the static page it's going to resize to 500px max. You'll need to upload the file to a photo post and get the High Res URL or host the image elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you all! At the end the solution proposed by @Ally worked perfectly. It's amazing that a simple thing like this is so tricky even on a blogging platform like Tumblr. Best wishes to all of you for a happy new year!